# OpenLDAP structure mulitple locations

Tags: openldap

I am new to OpenLDAP and I am a bit stuck with the structure.

Everywhere I see examples like this:

```
dc=our,dc=company,dc=com
-ou=USERS
-ou=GROUPS
-ou=ROLES
```

Our company has more geographical locations, how should I implement those locations?

Currently we have Novell eDirectory which works with a tree level:

```
   o=company
   -ou=BELGIUM
       user1
       user2
      -OU=GROUPS
      -OU=PROGRAMS
   -ou=NETHERLANDS
       user1
       user2
      -OU=GROUPS
      -OU=PROGRAMS
```

What is the best way to implement those locations in OpenLDAP?

Kr,

Joeri

Answer (score 1):

There is no best way. You have to think long and hard about how you want to use your data in order to structure it in a way that makes most sense for you, and also look into how your client software will use the directory.

As an example, if the structure of your company relies on strict separation, a tree like in your eDirectory example might be useful. For every location, you could use e.g. `ou=NL,dc=example,dc=com` as the base DN.

However, if your company is less strictly separated and it might happen that e.g. a user from the Netherlands needs to log in in Belgium, this might lead to problems and you could be better off with a separatation at a lower level, e.g. `ou=NL,cn=users,dc=example,dc=com` and `ou=BE,cn=users,dc=example,dc=com`.

Since you migrate away from another LDAP system, you are in an excellent position: If your current tree structure works for you, there is no need to change it, but if not this might be a chance to fix it now.

Comment: I agree and more... To use dc attribute is nosense for many LDAP trees. LDAP commonly represents a company and not a single domain. dc=example,dc=com can be o=Company.